# Security Topic - IS is_granted(ROLE_ADMIN) in TWIG enough?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I wanted to know if doing only a is_granted(ROLE_ADMIN) in twig is enough to secure a form.

I mean the form is available to anyone:
- some widget with choice selection are available to anyone to change.
- other widgets (widget about administration in the same form)  are only displayed if ROLE_ADMIN is granted.

**Is it enough to make it safe for administration stuff in this form to be only changed by the ROLE_ADMIN ? Or should I secure as well the controller.**

(securing the controller would make me write much more, because right now I just have to do a flush(). then I would have to make many more tests for all the POST I got through the form request)

Comment: I don't know your code but I would prefer to add/remove some form fields (basing on the user role) when you build the form in your form type (manually or with a form event) to avoid that checks.

Comment: ok, then it would be secured if I do it in the formType?

Comment: IMHO yes (I suppose you use also a `crsf_token`) and if you want you can add (dinamically using a condition or an event) also a `validation_group` specified for this admin field/s. In any case I used to write a test for all my forms to prevent any possible issue and to learn how to improve the code.

Comment: IMHO?? , yes I use a crsf_token.

Comment: how can I simulate a POST to check if the token is enough to block POST field which are not actually display in my page.

Comment: IMHO = in my honest opinion. Because without see your code I'm not able to guaranteed nothing (but i think is enough). Write a test case to know if is enough for you.

Comment: this is another question but read the [docs about testing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/index.html) and [how to unit test forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/unit_testing.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## General recommendations

It depends on what you mean by *security*. And, it depends on your definition of *secure enough* as well.

Following questions might help:

- Is it an internal-use application (such as a company-internal calendaring app where no sensitive data is stored or exposed)
- Is it important to ensure security against purposely malformed requests (which I'd consider everytime the answer for the first question is 'yes'). But even if the answer to the former question is 'no', sometimes you can have malformed requests even in an internal calendaring app... it all depends on what you consider a security threat and what not. And, on your users.

If you don't secure it in the controller, then a user might submit an arbitrary POST request with the fields that are not displayed there, if she guesses the names of the fields correctly, or finds them somewhere. So, in my opinion, you should always double check for sanity.

You could:

- ('pure' solution, more time-consuming) Separate the admin widgets by dynamically generating the form type depending on the users' privileges. Then you can always check for their existence in Twig, prior to the HTML generation. If you don't use the FormType, then I'd suggest you to do so - but you can dynamically add fields even if you build the whole form in the controller.
- ('dirty' solution, but easy and fast to implement) Check for that role when handling the form submission in the controller (which you suggested).

And as an answer to your question in comments: "how can I simulate a POST to check if the token is enough to block POST field which are not actually display in my page." I can recommend you the [Chrome Advanced Rest Client](https://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fadvanced-rest-client%2Fhgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo&ei=QdPsVNbWCdHPaImHguAG&usg=AFQjCNEo489FdO7M0eVz4c9u475vROBbXQ&sig2=cu5NfUdSv0VCJeEdQg8GNw&bvm=bv.86475890,d.bGQ) extension, if you use Google Chrome for development. I use it to test my forms with great success.

**So, to sum it up, I think that the question is not clearly stated and cannot be answered generally. It all depends. But if you want a simple answer: it's not secure enough. Hiding something from one's eyes doesn't mean it's secure. Therefore...**

## Specific recommendations - a solution with a form event listener

This is how I would do it for maximum security (I use PHP 5.5 here, so ensure you have it or it needs some syntax tweaking).

In your `FormType`, register an event listener like such:

```
(...)

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('product_id', 'hidden');

    (...)

    $dynamicFieldCreatorFunc = function (FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if ($this->getContainer()->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'))
        {
            $form->add('admin_field', 'choice', [
                'choices' => [1 => 'Choice 1', 2 => 'Choice 2'],
            ]);
        }
    };

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, $dynamicFieldCreatorFunc);
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, $dynamicFieldCreatorFunc);
}
```

Then, if a user is not an admin one, your form will not have these fields generated. Of course in Twig, if you render your widgets one by one, you should check for the field's existence prior to rendering them:

```
{% if form.admin_field is defined %}
    {{ form_widget(form.admin_field) }}
{% endif %}
```

Or, using a shorter syntax with the newest Twig

```
{% form.admin_field is defined ? form_widget(form.admin_field) }}
```

Comment: ok thanks Xanatos, I will use the pure solution, generating fields in the FormType depending on the ROLE. I hope it is enough to prevent malware users from submiting arbitrary POST request. **Just one more question:** how does symfony know that those posts are arbitrary POST if I use the pure solution? does the token play a role in that?

Comment: @XanatosLightfirien , is the PRE_SUMIT event listener necessary in you exemple? Or the fact that the form doesnot have the field make that those attribute in Article Instance in the DB cannot be change by a malware user?

Comment: @Aleqxs The default Symfony token generation algorithm generates same CSRF token for all forms per user + site (because the token is nothing more than a SHA1 hash of the app's secret phrase, 'intention' - which is by default not given and can be overriden in the FormType by using setDefaults, and the session ID). So the token doesn't contain any information about the fields. But the session ID is connected with the user roles, because the user is read from the provider. Each time this form is constructed for a user, it contains only the fields that are allowed for her, thanks to the listeners.

Comment: @Aleqxs both listeners are necessary. PRE_SET_DATA is used when you set the form's default data on construction; when you bind the submitted data, PRE_SUBMIT is executed. If you don't call the listener on that event, the form will not register necessary fields and data will not be bound to them. To answer your question - yes, if the form has no field, it shall not be bound, thus it won't have any effect on the DB. If a form doesn't allow extraFields (you can look that up in the Sf docs), it's isValid method shall yield false when a malicious user submits a field that shouldn't be in that form.